# Is there a way to examine all ajax calls from a webbrowser control in C#?

Tags: c#, xmlhttprequest

I am making a simple web browser to navigate to any website and watch the ajax calls in C#. (Just like firefox and chrome allows you to do in their developer tools.) I want to be able to do this without the use of fiddler.

I am very new to C# and I do not know how to go about listening to these xhr.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Do you want this examination to happen "client-side" (in your custom browser) or in the server? These are two VERY different questions. If the answer is in your custom browser, then we need some portion of your code to help you.

Comment: good idea indeed, but why you want to that

Comment: @Jaxidian I want to do this straight inside my custom browser. The only code I have is what Visual Studio 2012 already generates when creating a form and the webbrowser control.

Comment: @Mustafa I want to better understand the browsers role in performing xmlhttprequests.